# Documentation on WebView.destroy()

Tags: android, webview

I was facing a problem with WebViews where the WebView core threads would not stop even after the activity/fragment ondestroy was called. To solve the problem I would call webview.destroy() explicitly in the ondestroy() of the fragment. I read the documentation about the destroy() method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#destroy%28%29

The documentation says "This method should be called after this WebView has been removed from the view system". Does it mean that I have to remove the WebView from the parent view that holds the WebView before I call the destroy()? Since I am calling the webview.destroy() in the onDestroy() of the frag and since onDestroyView() would have been called do I need to remove the webview from its parent?